# Use sys.argv[] inside ipython3 notebook

Tags: ipython

Is there a way for "ipython3 notebook" to receive command line arguments with its 'run' button?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the Cell -> Run menu item? If so, no. The notebook's not really designed to be used like that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to pass command line arguments into Ipython working environment. As you said, I just realise that it cannot be done with ipython.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem when I tried to run some scripts using `argparse` library in `Jupyter Notebook`. Since I don't want to do much modification to the code, I needed to provide `sys.argv[]` to the parser.
In my case, such code can solve the problem:

```
import sys
sys.argv=['self.py','arg1','arg2']
```

Because in a real command line, the first element of `sys.argv` is the name of the script, so you have to provide a random script name or a name that suitable for your application, and the following arguments are just like they are passed by a real command line.
This works for me so far, but I don't know if it is safe and elegant, wish this could help you.